# Match all occurrences of string using re.findall

Tags: python, regex

I have a string

`a = "123 some_string ABC 456 some_string DEF 789 some_string GHI"`

```
print re.findall("(\d\d\d).*([A-Z]+)", a)
```

**o/p** : `[('123', 'I')]`

**Expected o/p** : `[('123', 'ABC'), ('456', 'DEF'), ('789', 'GHI')]`

Because of `.*` it is matching `123` and final character `I`. 
What is the proper regex, so that it prints expected o/p ?

Comment: Make it non-greedy: [`(\d{3}).*?([A-Z]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/oL1lR1/1)

Comment: @anubhava Post an answer.

Comment: @ anubhava Thanks It worked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While anubhava's expression works, consider using the principle of contrast (108 steps compared to 30 steps - a reduction by more than 70%!):

```
(\d{3})[^A-Z]*([A-Z]+)
```

See the [**hijacked demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/oL1lR1/2).
The lazy dot-star is very expensive in terms of performance.

Comment: This is a much better alternative considering the current requirements.  If there is a restriction on the minimal amount of the uppercased part, a tempered greedy token would be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Converting my comment to an answer:

You are using greedy `.*` that is matching first 3 digit number to very last text starting with upper case alphabet.

You should make it non-greedy (lazy):

```
(\d{3}).*?([A-Z]+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oL1lR1/1)